# SOAP doesn't work

Tags: php, xml, soap, nusoap

I trying to work with SOAP, but it doesn't work. I tried localhost and another server. For example:
**soap.xml:**

```
POST /InStock HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: nnn

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">

<soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
  <m:GetStockPrice>
    <m:StockName>IBM</m:StockName>
  </m:GetStockPrice>
</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

and result is:

> XML Parsing Error: syntax error
>   Location:
>   http://w3.localhost/soap/soap.xml Line
>   Number 1, Column 1:POST /InStock
>   HTTP/1.1 ^

**phpinfo:**

```
soap
Soap Client     enabled
Soap Server     enabled
```

**apache mime.types**

```
application/fastsoap
application/soap+fastinfoset
application/soap+xml
```

I tried with nusoap too, but example.php shows me this error:

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class soapclient in C:\xampp\htdocs\w3\soap\nusoap.php on line 3896`

Thanks for any help and sorry for my English.

Comment: what version of php are you using? on another note, SOAP is built into PHP5, so there shouldn't be a need to use NuSOAP

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.1, but if I don't use PHP( just simple go to soap.xml) it's shows XML Parsing Error?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the PHP version is out of date. SOAP is built into PHP5, so there shouldn't be a need to use NuSOAP.

Note: I want to say that there are actually many non SOAP related problems that can cause that error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the HTTP-Header from your soap.xml, so that only the valid payload (SOAP/XML) remains and it should work.